# ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND(file:///android_asset/www/index.htm) & ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED(http://localhost/)

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, angular8

I have two error after update Angular 7 to 8 and update @ionic/angular 4.6.0 to 4.11.9
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND(file:///android_asset/www/index.htm) 
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED(http://localhost/)

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z22b5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Ionic commands:

```
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova run android
```

Comment: That's what I do.

    ionic cordova platform rm android && ionic cordova platform add android
    ionic cordova build android

Comment: try `ionic cordova run android`

Answer (score 0):

That's what I do.

```
ionic cordova platform rm android && ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova build android
```

Comment: edit your question and delete your answer   if  you add details.